# In the C# back end, how can I select an element in a Segmented Control?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm using a custom control to create joined buttons that display like this:

```
********************************************
*            *            *                *
*    One     *    Two     *     Three      *
*            *            *                *
********************************************
```

When I click the buttons then an event is fired:

```
void OnValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     switch (segControl.SelectedValue)
     {
```

This is working well but what I would like to do is to be able to select one of those buttons from within my C# code.

When I look at the source code for the control I cannot see how to do this.

Would appreciate if anyone has any suggestions on what I should do to for example select the 2nd button in the same way as if I had clicked on it.

Here is the code I am using:

```
<local:SegmentedControl ValueChanged="OnValueChanged" SelectedSegment="{Binding CustomPointsSwitch}" x:Name="segControl" HorizontalOptions="End">
   <local:SegmentedControl.Children>
       <local:SegmentedControlOption Text="Two" />
       <local:SegmentedControlOption Text="Four" />
   </local:SegmentedControl.Children>
</local:SegmentedControl>
```

**Shared Code**

```
public class SegmentedControl : View, IViewContainer<SegmentedControlOption>
{
    public IList<SegmentedControlOption> Children { get; set; }

    public SegmentedControl()
    {
        Children = new List<SegmentedControlOption>();
    }

    public event ValueChangedEventHandler ValueChanged;

    public delegate void ValueChangedEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);

    private string selectedValue;

    public string SelectedValue
    {
        get { return selectedValue; }
        set
        {
            selectedValue = value;
            if (ValueChanged != null)
                ValueChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
    public static readonly BindableProperty SelectedSegmentProperty = BindableProperty.Create("SelectedSegment", typeof(int), typeof(SegmentedControl), 0);
    public int SelectedSegment
    {
        get
        {
            return (int)GetValue(SelectedSegmentProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(SelectedSegmentProperty, value);
        }
    }
}

public class SegmentedControlOption : View
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty TextProperty = BindableProperty.Create("Text", typeof(string), typeof(SegmentedControlOption), string.Empty);

    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

**iOS Renderer**

```
public class SegmentedControlRenderer : ViewRenderer<SegmentedControl, UISegmentedControl>
{
    public SegmentedControlRenderer()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<SegmentedControl> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        var segmentedControl = new UISegmentedControl();
        for (var i = 0; i < e.NewElement.Children.Count; i++)
        {
            segmentedControl.InsertSegment(e.NewElement.Children[i].Text, i, false);
        }

        segmentedControl.ValueChanged += (sender, eventArgs) => {
            e.NewElement.SelectedSegment = (int)segmentedControl.SelectedSegment;
            e.NewElement.SelectedValue = segmentedControl.TitleAt(segmentedControl.SelectedSegment);
        };

        SetNativeControl(segmentedControl);
    }
}
```

**Android Renderer**

```
public class SegmentedControlRenderer : ViewRenderer<SegmentedControl, RadioGroup>
{

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<SegmentedControl> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        var layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)Context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);

        var g = new RadioGroup(Context);
        g.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
        g.CheckedChange += (sender, eventArgs) => {
            var rg = (RadioGroup)sender;
            if (rg.CheckedRadioButtonId != -1)
            {
                var id = rg.CheckedRadioButtonId;
                var radioButton = rg.FindViewById(id);
                var radioId = rg.IndexOfChild(radioButton);
                var btn = (RadioButton)rg.GetChildAt(radioId);
                var selection = (String)btn.Text;
                e.NewElement.SelectedValue = selection;
            }
        };

        for (var i = 0; i < e.NewElement.Children.Count; i++)
        {
            var o = e.NewElement.Children[i];
            var v = (SegmentedControlButton)layoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.SegmentedControl, null);
            v.Text = o.Text;
            if (i == 0)
                v.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.segmented_control_first_background);
            else if (i == e.NewElement.Children.Count - 1)
                v.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.segmented_control_last_background);
            g.AddView(v);
        }

        SetNativeControl(g);
    }
}

public class SegmentedControlButton : RadioButton
{
    private int lineHeightSelected;
    private int lineHeightUnselected;
    private Paint linePaint;

    public SegmentedControlButton(Context context, IAttributeSet attributes) : this(context, attributes, Resource.Attribute.segmentedControlOptionStyle)
    {
    }

    public SegmentedControlButton(Context context, IAttributeSet attributes, int defStyle) : base(context, attributes, defStyle)
    {
        Initialize(attributes, defStyle);
    }

    private void Initialize(IAttributeSet attributes, int defStyle)
    {
        var a = this.Context.ObtainStyledAttributes(attributes, Resource.Styleable.SegmentedControlOption, defStyle, Resource.Style.SegmentedControlOption);

        var lineColor = a.GetColor(Resource.Styleable.SegmentedControlOption_lineColor, 0);
        linePaint = new Paint();
        linePaint.Color = lineColor;

        lineHeightUnselected = a.GetDimensionPixelSize(Resource.Styleable.SegmentedControlOption_lineHeightUnselected, 0);
        lineHeightSelected = a.GetDimensionPixelSize(Resource.Styleable.SegmentedControlOption_lineHeightSelected, 0);

        a.Recycle();
    }

    protected override void OnDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        base.OnDraw(canvas);

        if (linePaint.Color != 0 && (lineHeightSelected > 0 || lineHeightUnselected > 0))
        {
            var lineHeight = Checked ? lineHeightSelected : lineHeightUnselected;

            if (lineHeight > 0)
            {
                var rect = new Rect(0, Height - lineHeight, Width, Height);
                canvas.DrawRect(rect, linePaint);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would appreciate any suggestions on how I can make the change.  Also does anyone have an insights as to if Xamarin are looking to make this into a forms component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you had a chance to look at this [plugin](https://github.com/alexrainman/SegmentedControl) - it seems perfectly suited for what you are trying to achieve.

For being able to programmatically select a segment - i.e. `SelectedSegment` - you need to implement this at renderer level, and have them translate this selection to native controls. Furthermore, it is also recommended to override `OnElementPropertyChanged` method to subscribe to property changes (such as `SelectedSegment`) and ensure that the native control state stays in sync with the shared forms element, and vice-versa.

---

*EDIT - 1: Add code sample*

**Shared code**

```
public class SegmentedControl : View, IViewContainer<SegmentedControlOption>
{
    public IList<SegmentedControlOption> Children { get; set; }

    public SegmentedControl()
    {
        Children = new List<SegmentedControlOption>();
    }

    public event EventHandler ValueChanged;
    public static readonly BindableProperty SelectedValueProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(
            "SelectedValue", typeof(string), typeof(SegmentedControl),
            defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay,
            defaultValue: default(string), propertyChanged: OnSelectedValueChanged);

    public string SelectedValue
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(SelectedValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedValueProperty, value); }
    }

    static void OnSelectedValueChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        ((SegmentedControl)bindable).OnSelectedValueChangedImpl((string)oldValue, (string)newValue);
    }

    protected virtual void OnSelectedValueChangedImpl(string oldValue, string newValue)
    {
        ValueChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        SelectedSegment = GetSelectedIndex(SelectedValue);
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty SelectedSegmentProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(
            "SelectedSegment", typeof(int), typeof(SegmentedControl),
            defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay,
            defaultValue: default(int), propertyChanged: OnSelectedSegmentChanged);

    public int SelectedSegment
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(SelectedSegmentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedSegmentProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void OnSelectedSegmentChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        ((SegmentedControl)bindable).OnSelectedSegmentChangedImpl((int)oldValue, (int)newValue);
    }

    protected virtual void OnSelectedSegmentChangedImpl(int oldValue, int newValue)
    {
        SelectedValue = GetSelectedValue(SelectedSegment);
    }

    int GetSelectedIndex(object selectedItem)
    {
        if (selectedItem == null)
            return -1;

        if (selectedItem is string optionText)
            return Children.IndexOf(Children.FirstOrDefault(x => Equals(x.Text, optionText)));

        return -1;
    }

    string GetSelectedValue(int index)
    {
        if (index >= 0 && index < Children.Count)
            return Children[index].Text;

        return null;
    }
}

//Keep SegmentedControlOption as same (No changes needed)
public class SegmentedControlOption : View
{
    ...
}
```

**iOS renderer**

```
public class SegmentedControlRenderer : ViewRenderer<SegmentedControl, UISegmentedControl>
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<SegmentedControl> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        UISegmentedControl segmentedControl = null;
        if (Control == null)
        {
            segmentedControl = new UISegmentedControl();

            for (var i = 0; i < e.NewElement.Children.Count; i++)
            {
                segmentedControl.InsertSegment(Element.Children[i].Text, i, false);
            }

            SetNativeControl(segmentedControl);
            SetSelectedSegment();
        }

        if (e.OldElement != null)
        {
            // Unsubscribe from event handlers and cleanup any resources
            if (segmentedControl != null)
                segmentedControl.ValueChanged -= NativeValueChanged;
        }

        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            // Configure the control and subscribe to event handlers
            segmentedControl.ValueChanged += NativeValueChanged;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

        if (e.PropertyName == nameof(SegmentedControl.SelectedSegment))
            SetSelectedSegment();
    }

    void NativeValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Element is SegmentedControl formsElement)
        {
            formsElement.SelectedSegment = (int)Control.SelectedSegment;
        };
    }

    void SetSelectedSegment()
    {
        if (Element is SegmentedControl formsElement)
        {
            if (formsElement.SelectedSegment >= 0 && formsElement.SelectedSegment < Control.NumberOfSegments)
                Control.SelectedSegment = formsElement.SelectedSegment;
        }
    }
}
```

**Android renderer**

```
public class SegmentedControlRenderer : ViewRenderer<SegmentedControl, RadioGroup>
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<SegmentedControl> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        RadioGroup nativeControl = null;
        if (Control == null)
        {
            // Instantiate the native control and assign it to the Control property with the SetNativeControl method
            var layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)Context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
            nativeControl = new RadioGroup(Context)
            {
                Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal
            };

            for (var i = 0; i < e.NewElement.Children.Count; i++)
            {
                var o = e.NewElement.Children[i];
                var v = (SegmentedControlButton)layoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.SegmentedControl, null);
                v.Text = o.Text;
                if (i == 0)
                    v.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.segmented_control_first_background);
                else if (i == e.NewElement.Children.Count - 1)
                    v.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.segmented_control_last_background);
                nativeControl.AddView(v);
            }

            SetNativeControl(nativeControl);
            SetSelectedSegment();
        }

        if (e.OldElement != null)
        {
            // Unsubscribe from event handlers and cleanup any resources
            if (nativeControl != null)
                nativeControl.CheckedChange -= NativeCheckedChanged;
        }

        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            nativeControl.CheckedChange += NativeCheckedChanged;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

        if (e.PropertyName == nameof(SegmentedControl.SelectedSegment))
            SetSelectedSegment();
    }

    void NativeCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Element is SegmentedControl formsElement)
        {
            var rg = (RadioGroup)sender;
            if (rg.CheckedRadioButtonId != -1)
            {
                var id = rg.CheckedRadioButtonId;
                var radioButton = rg.FindViewById(id);
                var radioIndex = rg.IndexOfChild(radioButton);
                formsElement.SelectedSegment = radioIndex;
            }
        };
    }

    void SetSelectedSegment()
    {
        if (Element is SegmentedControl formsElement)
        {
            if (formsElement.SelectedSegment >= 0 && formsElement.SelectedSegment < Control.ChildCount)
            {
                var radioBtn = (RadioButton)Control.GetChildAt(formsElement.SelectedSegment);
                radioBtn.Checked = true;
            }
        }
    }
}

//Keep SegmentedControlOption as same (No changes needed)
public class SegmentedControlButton : RadioButton
{ 
    ...
}
```

---

### Sample Usage

[image]

```
<StackLayout Margin="20">
    <local:SegmentedControl ValueChanged="OnValueChanged" SelectedSegment="{Binding CustomPointsSwitch}" x:Name="segControl" HorizontalOptions="End">
        <local:SegmentedControl.Children>
            <local:SegmentedControlOption Text="One" />
            <local:SegmentedControlOption Text="Two" />
            <local:SegmentedControlOption Text="Three" />
        </local:SegmentedControl.Children>
    </local:SegmentedControl>

    <Label Text="{Binding Path=SelectedSegment, StringFormat='Selected Segment: {0}', Source={x:Reference segControl}}" />
    <Label Text="{Binding Path=SelectedValue, StringFormat='Selected Value: {0}', Source={x:Reference segControl}}" />

    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Text="Select One" Command="{Binding SelectCommand}" CommandParameter="0" HorizontalOptions="Start" />
        <Button Text="Select Two" Command="{Binding SelectCommand}" CommandParameter="1" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        <Button Text="Select Three" Command="{Binding SelectCommand}" CommandParameter="2" HorizontalOptions="End" />
    </StackLayout>

    <Button Text="Set selection using SelectedValue" Clicked="Handle_Clicked" />
</StackLayout>
```

**Code behind**

```
public partial class SegmentedSamplePage : ContentPage
{
    public SegmentedSamplePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.BindingContext = new PageViewModel
        {
            CustomPointsSwitch = 1
        };
    }

    void OnValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(this.segControl.SelectedValue);
    }

    void Handle_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        this.segControl.SelectedValue = "Two";
    }
}

public class PageViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    int _customPointsSwitch;
    public int CustomPointsSwitch
    {
        get { return _customPointsSwitch; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _customPointsSwitch, value, nameof(CustomPointsSwitch));
        }
    }

    Command _selectCommand;
    public Command SelectCommand => _selectCommand ?? (_selectCommand = new Command((object param) =>
             {
                 if (Int32.TryParse(param?.ToString(), out int index))
                     CustomPointsSwitch = index;
             }));
}
```

## Github: [link](https://github.com/shads-labs/SegmentedControlSample)

Comment: I downloaded the plugin and tried to get it to work but it comes up with multiple errors and I cannot get it to run on my VS running on a Mac.  I think I would prefer to keep things simple and if possible extend what I have but I am not sure how to do this.  Sounds from what you say that it could be a little bit more involved but hopefully someone can come up with some suggestions that I could use.  Do you have any idea why Xamarin didn't implement something like this themselves?

Comment: I don't believe XamarinForms has something that works out of the box. By `downloading it` did you mean you tried to build the source code, or tried installing the nuget plugin as a package to your project? If you don't want to install a package, I think all you need to do is copy SegmentedControl.cs, SegmentedControlRenderer (Android), and SegmentedControlRenderer (iOS). I am assuming that you already have the requisite resource files in Android project for the drawables. If not, then copy that too.

Comment: Hi, I tried downloading the project and running that.  But it came up with numerous errors when I tried to build it. I will have a look into copying those files.  In the mean time if you feel like having a look at what I have in the example and seeing if that could easily be changed then I would also be happy to answer that question and award the bonus points. Thanks

Comment: Hi Sharada,  If you have a chance to come up with a solution I'd be happy to award the bounty.  Thanks

Comment: That's great.  Thanks very much!

Comment: Hi @samantha-j-t-star : I have updated the answer with code. Hope it helps!. Also, added a github sample.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just set margins in shared xaml?

```
<local:SegmentedControl ValueChanged="OnValueChanged" SelectedSegment="{Binding CustomPointsSwitch}" x:Name="segControl" HorizontalOptions="End">
   <local:SegmentedControl.Children>
       <local:SegmentedControlOption Text="Two" Margin="8,0,8,0" />
       <local:SegmentedControlOption Text="Four" Margin="8,0,8,0" />
   </local:SegmentedControl.Children>
</local:SegmentedControl>
```

Comment: Tried this but it has no effect