# How to change tintcolor of segmented control in Android?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I found this for creating `SegmentedControl` for both iOS and Android:

[In the C# back end, how can I select an element in a Segmented Control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47132181/in-the-c-sharp-back-end-how-can-i-select-an-element-in-a-segmented-control?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

I want to change the colors of the control programmatically like the image below:

[image]

So I added the following code:

**In Shared code:**

```
public class SegmentedControl : View, IViewContainer<SegmentedControlOption>
    {
        // Other codes here

        public static readonly BindableProperty TintColorProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(TintColor), typeof(Color), typeof(SegmentedControl), Color.Blue, BindingMode.OneWay);
        public Color TintColor
        {
            get { return (Color)GetValue(TintColorProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TintColorProperty, value); }
        }
        // Other codes here
}
```

**In iOS renderer:**

```
public class SegmentedControlRenderer : ViewRenderer<SegmentedControl, UISegmentedControl>
   {
      protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<SegmentedControl> e)
      {
         base.OnElementChanged(e);
         // more codes here

        segmentedControl.TintColor = e.NewElement?.TintColor.ToUIColor();

         // more codes here
      }

      protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
      {
         base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

         if (e.PropertyName == SegmentedControl.TintColorProperty.PropertyName)
                SetSegmentTintColor();
      }
      void SetSegmentTintColor()
      {
         if (Element is SegmentedControl formsElement)
                Control.TintColor = formsElement.TintColor.ToUIColor();
      }
   }
```

**In XAML**

```
<local:SegmentedControl ValueChanged="OnModeChanged" x:Name="segControlMode" HorizontalOptions="End" TintColor="Red" > 
   <local:SegmentedControl.Children>
      <local:SegmentedControlOption Text="Learn" />
      <local:SegmentedControlOption Text="Quiz" />
   </local:SegmentedControl.Children>
</local:SegmentedControl>
```

As you can see in the image above this works for iOS, but I have no idea how to apply this changes to android. Anyone has any idea how this is done?

Comment: The link you provided already told you how it is done. Could you please be more specific with your problem?

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT Sorry if its not clear. But what I wanted to do is change the control colors in android programmatically as seen in the image above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what I wanted to do is change the control colors in android programmatically as seen in the image above.

The sample you provided set the background through static Styles. If you want to set the color programmatically , you can follow below steps to make changes to the sample project:

1. Comment out two lines of `SegmentedControlOption` style in `Resource/values/styles.xml` so that it doesn't use static resource to set the background and textcolor:

   ```
   <style name="SegmentedControlOption" parent="@android:style/Widget.CompoundButton.RadioButton">
       <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
       <!--<item name="android:background">@drawable/segmented_control_background</item>-->
       <item name="android:button">@null</item>
       <!--<item name="android:textColor">@color/segmented_control_text</item>-->

       <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
       <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
       <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
       <item name="android:minWidth">85dp</item>
       <item name="android:minHeight">@dimen/segmented_control_default_height</item>
       <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/segmented_control_text_size</item>
       ...
   ```
2. Modify `SegmentedControlRenderer`  to codes below:

   ```
   public class SegmentedControlRenderer : ViewRenderer<SegmentedControl, RadioGroup>
   {
       public SegmentedControlRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
       { }
       protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<SegmentedControl> e)
       {
           base.OnElementChanged(e);
           RadioGroup nativeControl = null;
           Android.Graphics.Color themeColor = Android.Graphics.Color.Red;
           if (e.NewElement != null)
           {
               themeColor = e.NewElement.TintColor.ToAndroid();
           }

           if (Control == null)
           {
               // Instantiate the native control and assign it to the Control property with the SetNativeControl method
               var layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)Context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
               nativeControl = new RadioGroup(Context)
               {
                   Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal
               };

               for (var i = 0; i < e.NewElement.Children.Count; i++)
               {
                   var o = e.NewElement.Children[i];
                   var v = (SegmentedControlButton)layoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.SegmentedControl, null);
                   v.Text = o.Text;
                   //Create a shape act as the background of the button
                   v.ThemeColor=themeColor;
                   if (i == 0)
                   {
                       //Specifies radii for each of the 4 corners. For each corner, the array contains 2 values, [X_radius, Y_radius].
                       //The corners are ordered top-left, top-right, bottom-right, bottom-left. This property is honored only when the shape is of type RECTANGLE.
                       v.ChangeCornerRadius(8,0,0,8);
                   }
                   else if (i == e.NewElement.Children.Count - 1)
                   {
                       v.ChangeCornerRadius(0, 8, 8, 0);
                   }
                   v.CheckedChange += (s, args) =>
                   {
                       if (args.IsChecked)
                       {
                           (v.Background as GradientDrawable).SetColor(themeColor);
                           v.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.White);
                       }
                       else
                       {
                           (v.Background as GradientDrawable).SetColor(Android.Graphics.Color.White);
                           v.SetTextColor(themeColor);
                       }
                   };

                   //if (i == 0)
                   //  v.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.segmented_control_first_background);
                   //else if (i == e.NewElement.Children.Count - 1)
                   //  v.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.segmented_control_last_background);
                   nativeControl.AddView(v);
               }

               SetNativeControl(nativeControl);
               SetSelectedSegment();
           }

           if (e.OldElement != null)
           {
               // Unsubscribe from event handlers and cleanup any resources
               if (nativeControl != null)
                   nativeControl.CheckedChange -= NativeCheckedChanged;
           }

           if (e.NewElement != null)
           {
               nativeControl.CheckedChange += NativeCheckedChanged;

           }
       }

       protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
       {
           base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

           if (e.PropertyName == nameof(SegmentedControl.SelectedSegment))
               SetSelectedSegment();
       }

       void NativeCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           if (Element is SegmentedControl formsElement)
           {
               var rg = (RadioGroup)sender;
               if (rg.CheckedRadioButtonId != -1)
               {
                   var id = rg.CheckedRadioButtonId;
                   var radioButton = rg.FindViewById(id);
                   var radioIndex = rg.IndexOfChild(radioButton);
                   formsElement.SelectedSegment = radioIndex;
               }
           };
       }

       void SetSelectedSegment()
       {
           if (Element is SegmentedControl formsElement)
           {
               if (formsElement.SelectedSegment >= 0 && formsElement.SelectedSegment < Control.ChildCount)
               {
                   var radioBtn = (RadioButton)Control.GetChildAt(formsElement.SelectedSegment);
                   radioBtn.Checked = true;
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Modify `SegmentedControlButton` to codes below:

   ```
   public class SegmentedControlButton : RadioButton
   {
       private int lineHeightSelected;
       private int lineHeightUnselected;
       private Paint linePaint;

       private Android.Graphics.Color _themeColor;
       public Android.Graphics.Color ThemeColor {
           get { return this._themeColor; }
           set {
               this._themeColor = value;
               if (this.Background != null)
               {
                   var background = (this.Background as GradientDrawable);
                   if (this.Checked)
                   {
                       background.SetColor(value);
                       background.SetStroke(2, value);
                       this.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.White);
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       background.SetColor(Android.Graphics.Color.White);
                       background.SetStroke(2, value);
                       this.SetTextColor(value);
                   }
               }
           }
       }

       public SegmentedControlButton(Context context, IAttributeSet attributes) : this(context, attributes, Resource.Attribute.segmentedControlOptionStyle)
       {
       }

       public SegmentedControlButton(Context context, IAttributeSet attributes, int defStyle) : base(context, attributes, defStyle)
       {
           Initialize(attributes, defStyle);
       }


       private void Initialize(IAttributeSet attributes, int defStyle)
       {
           var a = this.Context.ObtainStyledAttributes(attributes, Resource.Styleable.SegmentedControlOption, defStyle, Resource.Style.SegmentedControlOption);

           var lineColor = a.GetColor(Resource.Styleable.SegmentedControlOption_lineColor, 0);
           linePaint = new Paint();
           linePaint.Color = lineColor;

           lineHeightUnselected = a.GetDimensionPixelSize(Resource.Styleable.SegmentedControlOption_lineHeightUnselected, 0);
           lineHeightSelected = a.GetDimensionPixelSize(Resource.Styleable.SegmentedControlOption_lineHeightSelected, 0);

           //default themecolor is set to red
           this._themeColor = Android.Graphics.Color.Red;
           GradientDrawable shape = new GradientDrawable();
           shape.SetShape(ShapeType.Rectangle);
           shape.SetColor(Android.Graphics.Color.White);
           shape.SetStroke(2, this._themeColor);
           this.SetBackground(shape);
           this.SetTextColor(this._themeColor);
           a.Recycle();
       }

       /// <summary>
       /// Change the Corner Radius
       /// </summary>
       /// <param name="topLeft"></param>
       /// <param name="topRight"></param>
       /// <param name="bottomRight"></param>
       /// <param name="bottomLeft"></param>
       public void ChangeCornerRadius(float topLeft,float topRight,float bottomRight,float bottomLeft)
       {
           if (this.Background != null)
           {
               var background = (this.Background as GradientDrawable);
               background.SetCornerRadii(new float[] { topLeft, topLeft, topRight, topRight, bottomRight, bottomRight, bottomLeft, bottomLeft });
           }
       }


       protected override void OnDraw(Canvas canvas)
       {
           base.OnDraw(canvas);

           if (linePaint.Color != 0 && (lineHeightSelected > 0 || lineHeightUnselected > 0))
           {
               var lineHeight = Checked ? lineHeightSelected : lineHeightUnselected;

               if (lineHeight > 0)
               {
                   var rect = new Rect(0, Height - lineHeight, Width, Height);
                   canvas.DrawRect(rect, linePaint);
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try this later when I get home. And will let you know.